# "Good to meet you" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

Is "Good to meet you" as grammatically correct as "Nice to meet you"?

I ask because saying "I'm good" is considered incorrect, because good relates to being moral or healthy.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to make it answerable? It’s very hard to answer your question as written because it comes with all these false assumptions built into it that nobody should accept, let alone take for granted. Whatever native speakers actually say is what is grammatically "correct", and whatever they find sounds wrong to them is what is grammatically "incorrect". Anything generated by native speakers is grammatical, and nothing they cannot generate is grammatical.

Comment: This kind of question, "Is X correct?", works better over on [ell.se]. But a generic answer is that language judgements aren't always so cleanly decided, good can mean all sorts of things, and different people judge things differently. "Good to meet you" sounds fine to me - a lot of people say it.

Comment: _Good_ doesn't mean 'morally good' here, it means that it is a good experience (pleasant or fortunate).

Comment: Opposition to "I'm good" is based more on prejudice than logic or evidence. So if you've been told not to use it by your teacher or boss, you may want to avoid it, but otherwise it is fine. (If you search ELU you'll find many questions about the phrase.)

Answer (score 1):

Both are short for "*It is {nice|good} to meet you.*", are grammatically correct, and mean almost the same thing.

There is a subtle difference between "good" and "nice" though.

If you comment on someone's shoes for instance:

- Those are good shoes.
  (I have the same brand, and they are very sturdy but comfortable.)
- Those are nice shoes.
  (The style suits you very well, especially with that jacket.)

"Good" refers to the practical use, while "nice" refers to how one feels about them:

- Good shoes might be really ugly.
- Nice shoes might be uncomfortable.

It's not that extreme a difference when meeting people, but there is still the slight implication of useful or pleasant:

- It's good to meet you. (I've been wanting to ask you about … .)
- It's nice to meet you. (Your personality and appearance cheer me up.)